# What would a "molecular debonding spray" do?

Tags: technology, biochemistry

I stumbled across this phrase on a sci-fi tech thread and I'm trying to understand what it means. What would an aerosols spray that "de-bonds" molecules do and mean?

Comment: strong acid can do that to a degree I guess

Comment: Can I suggest that you add the tags chemistry and physics?

Comment: Whatever it exactly does, it would be great for getting rid of waste and recycling stuff.

Comment: Well, there's fluorine spray and that would certainly do some molecular debonding.

Comment: Debond the container you try to keep it in?  See e.g. various fluorine-based chemicals.

Comment: You should ask on *that* thread, not here.

Comment: Alternatively, if you specify which universe this exists in (assuming it was claimed to exist in some sci-fi universe), you might be able to ask about *how it works there* over on [scifi.se], which concern themselves with *existing* science-fiction and fantasy universes and what goes on in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spray would interfere with the [van der Waals forces](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/lab-rat/holding-molecules-together-van-der-waals-forces/) holding molecules together.  This would result in a vapor or slurry of individual molecules.  I sure wouldn't want to breathe that vapor.  The slurry (if that's the form the unbonded material takes) would probably resolidify as the "debonding" agent evaporates.

Answer (score 3):

That is basically synonymous with a disintegration ray. Except the matter is still there just not in any shape it was. Probably in a cloud of ionic dust and gas

FYI: molecular bonds are the structures that hold atoms together in order to create molecules. So if you destroy those bonds you destroy the molecule, no molecule no water, cells, bone, teeth. For all intents and purposes this is basically a disintegration ray.

Answer (score 2):

The question is open to some interpretation. If the bonds being de-bonded (presumably removed) are covalent this would be synonymous with a disintegration ray as Anon said (Van der Waals bonding would also be removed along with the molecules and much else desides). As soon as the separated atoms left the disintegration beam they would react together reforming molecules as many atomic radicals are highly reactive. The molecules formed would not necessarily be of the same type as the original. For example alcohol might be converted to water, hydrogen and carbon soot. CH3CH2OH >>> 2C + 6H + O >>> H20 + 2H2 +2C although many other products are possible and would probably also form depending on circumstances.

If ionic bonds were involved the results would be similar. Common salt would be “debonded” into sodium and chlorine atoms or ions which on leaving the beam would rapidly recombine.

Both types of bond disruption would release vast amounts of energy as the atomic or ionic debris left the beam and reacted with themselves and their surroundings probably explosively leaving a horrible chemical mess.

If the bonds in question were only Van der Waals bonds, such as hydrogen bonds, then the materials physical state would be affected. Although the molecules would remain in intact as individual entities, there would be nothing holding one molecule to another and thermal motion would turn whatever substance the ray was pointed at into a gas. As soon as this gas left the beam Van der Waals forces would resume and the molecules would condense into solids and liquids again, but almost certainly not in the same form that they started out in. For example any one unfortunate enough to stand in such a ray would first be turned into a low temperature gas which would escape in all directions and then be re-condensed into a “slurry” (as Shadocat put it) of solids and liquids such as water, fat, Calcium phosphate and many other organic compounds as this gas left the beam.

Answer (score 0):

Put sulphuric acid in a spray bottle and test it out. Very carefully.

Like the "hydrospanner" of Starwars fame (aka monkey wrench), you give something real common an impressive sounding name. Acids and alkalines are "molecular debonding" agents. Put them in a spray bottle and you have a "molecular debonding aerosol".

Comment: Most of the ordinary spray bottles aren't okay for that, the acid would solve them and go out. Even with the few ones luckily not containing solvable parts, the **very, very** careful usage is strongly adviced. :-)

Comment: Most acids are stored in ordinary plastic or glass bottles. Metal and organic parts won't last long though

Comment: We're looking for answers rather than pointers to answers, so to speak.  This seems like more of a comment than an answer; please [edit] to expand it.  Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Edited per suggestion.

Comment: Update re "Most acids are stored in ordinary plastic or glass bottles" - personal experience.  My first summer job as a teenager was hand washing glassware in a chemical laboratory. I washed most pieces in hydrochloric acid before rinsing them in distilled water.